# VBA Copy and Paste Method Not Working

Tags: vba, excel, clipboard, copy-paste

I am trying to write a simple copy and paste macro and it works up until the last line.  When it hits the last line, it says the paste function will not work.  I am really confused why this is happening and any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sheet2.Columns("A:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Sheet2.Columns("F:G").Cut
Sheet2.Activate
Columns("A:B").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("SourceData").Columns("A:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Sheets("SourceData").Activate
Columns("A:B").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste                   <-LINE THAT THROWS ERROR
```

My error message is `Paste Method of Worksheet Class failed`

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: `Paste Method of Worksheet Class failed`

Comment: you have nothing to paste, when you insert the columns in your sourcedata sheet you lose your selection (cut Columns F:G)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a second cut (or copy) command to go with your second Activesheet.Paste command

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving the error because you have already emptied the clipboard with the first "cut/paste" operation.

Try this instead:

```
Sheet2.Columns("A:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Sheet2.Columns("F:G").Cut
Sheet2.Activate
Columns("A:B").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Activesheet.Columns("A:B").Copy

Sheets("SourceData").Columns("A:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Sheets("SourceData").Activate
Columns("A:B").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```