# Excel update macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a macro that will update an excel spreadsheet from another sheets information.   But, when updating I want to move two columns to the front because I don't want them to change.  Everything works up to the point where I move the two columns to the front.  I select them, cut them and paste them but for some reason right after the paste happens it throws an error saying the paste had failed (error 1004-PasteSpecial method of Range class failed).  I am very confused on why this is happening and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub crossUpdate()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng1Row As Range, rng2Row As Range, Key As Range, match As Integer
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = Workbooks("011 High Level Task List v2.xlsm")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("011 High Level Task List v2 ESI.xlsm")

'Unfilter and Unhide both sheets
With wb1.Sheets("Development Priority List")
.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
With wb2.Sheets("Development Priority List")
.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With

'Copy and paste original sheet to new temp sheet
wb1.Sheets("Development Priority List").Activate
wb1.Sheets("Development Priority List").Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add.Name = "SourceData"
wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Paste

'Sort temp sheet by key
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)
Set rng1Row = rng1.EntireRow
rng1Row.Sort Key1:=Sheets("SourceData").Range("A1")

'Update sheet sorted by key
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng2 = wb2.Sheets("Development Priority List").Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)
Set rng2Row = rng2.EntireRow
rng2Row.Sort Key1:=wb2.Sheets("Development Priority List").Range("A1")

'Dev columns moved on update sheet
 With wb2.Sheets("Development Priority List")
.Columns("F:G").Cut
.Columns("A:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
.Activate
.Columns("A:B").Select
End With
Selection.PasteSpecial       <------ Line that throws error
End Sub
```

Comment: this was already answered in another one of your posts.  Go back and look at it.  When you do the.activate you lose your selection/clipboard.

Comment: So I just delete the .activate?

Comment: After the .Insert line, add a line like this: .Columns("A:B").Copy  That should fix your issue.  See the answers in this question (one of yours) as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065376/vba-copy-and-paste-macro

Answer (score 0):

Change your block of code as such:

```
 With wb2.Sheets("Development Priority List")
    .Columns("A:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    .Columns("H:I").Cut
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial
End With
```